# Intern 3 raising weird error while clicking element

Tags: javascript, intern

I have faced this many times. I have a code setup where intern types certain input to the input element and click on submit button. But the intern is raising error while clicking in the button.
My code setup is as follows:

```
   // other tests

"Load Client":function(){


        var self = this
        return inputs.Clients.reduce(function (chain, client) {
            isNA = false;
            return chain
                .then(viewClientPage.clickOnAddClientBtn())
                .then(addClientModal.clientName.enterValue(client.ClientName))
                .then(function () {
                    return client.LineOfBusiness.reduce(function (chain1, lob) {
                        return chain1
                            .then(addClientModal.stateLOB.selectOption(lob.LOBName))
                            .then(addClientModal.state.clearValue())
                            .then(function () {
                                return lob.States.reduce(function (chain2, state) {
                                    if (state.StateName == 'N/A') {
                                        isNA = true;
                                        return chain2
                                            .then(addClientModal.selectAllStateCheckBox())
                                    } else {
                                        return chain2
                                            .then(addClientModal.state.enterValue(state.StateName))
                                    }
                                }, self.remote);
                            })
                            .then(addClientModal.clickOnAddStateBtn())



                    }, self.remote);
                })
                .sleep(6000)
                .findByXpath('//*[@id="saveModal"]').click().end() // this is raising error
        }, this.remote)

 }
```

And the error i'm getting is

```
          UnknownError: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/737b17818334be969beb0ce6a8174f12/element/0.48698099328565236-11/click] unknown error: Element <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save" style="float:right" ng-click="addNewPayer('Payers','clients/clients/partials/addNewPayerModal.tpl.html','...',client,editParameters)">Add Client</button> is not clickable at point (1296, 112). Other element would receive the click: <div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope custommodal-modal-edit in" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="" window-class="custommodal-modal-edit" size="lg" index="0" animate="animate" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">...</div>
   (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 
    (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 
      x86_64)
     at runRequest  <node_modules\leadfoot\Session.js:92:40>
     at <node_modules\leadfoot\Session.js:113:39>
     at new Promise  <node_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:411:3>
     at ProxiedSession._post  <node_modules\leadfoot\Session.js:67:10>
     at Element._post  <node_modules\leadfoot\Element.js:23:31>
     at Element.click  <node_modules\leadfoot\Element.js:197:15>
     at Command.<anonymous>  <node_modules\leadfoot\Command.js:680:19>
     at <node_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:393:15>
     at run  <node_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:237:7>
     at <node_modules\dojo\nextTick.ts:44:3>
     at Command.target.(anonymous function) [as click]  
    <node_modules\leadfoot\Command.js:674:11>
    at Command.<anonymous>  



<Automation\pageObjects\pages\clientSetup\clients\viewClientsPage\ViewClientPage.js:61:71>
         at runCallback  <node_modules\leadfoot\Command.js:526:31>
          at Command.<anonymous>  <node_modules\leadfoot\Command.js:543:11>
          at <node_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:393:15>
         at run  <node_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:237:7>
         at <node_modules\dojo\nextTick.ts:44:3>
         at _combinedTickCallback  <internal\process\next_tick.js:67:7>
         at process._tickCallback  <internal\process\next_tick.js:98:9>
         at Command.then  <node_modules\leadfoot\Command.js:542:10>
         at <Automation\Data_Load\LoadSM2Data.js:61:30>
         at Array.reduce  <native>
          at Test.Load Clients [as test]  <Automation\Data_Load\LoadSM2Data.js:56:35>
  at <node_modules\intern\lib\Test.js:191:24>
  at <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:393:15>
  at runCallbacks  <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:11:11>
  at <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:317:4>
  at run  <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:237:7>
  at <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\nextTick.ts:44:3>
```

I have tried changing the version of `seenium-server-standalone.jar`  `chromedriver.exe` and even tried using `findByXpath`, `findById` etc but none of them worked. Please help me through

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that a button with label "Add Client" isn't clickable because a modal dialog would receive the click. First, is this actually the button that should be clicked? If not, then the search term provided to `findBy` will need to be refined.

Assuming this is the correct button, is it being occluded by a modal dialog at the time the click action is happening? If so, take steps to ensure the dialog is closed.

Comment: yes it is the button that should be clicked and the button is on the modal dailog.. why is it tring to click the modal when i m providing the search term for buttton??

Comment: The search term is working properly -- as the error message indicates, chromedriver was told to click the button, but when it did, something else received the click (that's the bit about "button...is not clickable at point (1296, 112). Other element would receive the click...").

Comment: Is your browser's zoom level set to 100%? If it's not, chromedriver can be confused about where clicks are actually happening.